# Laravel 5 set default value to Select2

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I populated my Select option using laravel collective htmlServiceProvider

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     {!! Form::label('Serial'  ,null,['class'=>'small']) !!}
     {!! Form::select('cross_match_id',$serials,null,['class'=>'select2 input-sm form-control','id'=>'cross_match_id']) !!}
</div>
```

I set my the default value from the database using Jquery

```
$('#cross_match_id').val(data.cross_match_id);
```

If I don't use [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) the default value and value's text will be set. But when I use Select2 its just empty. Although I can see that it has default value but not set.

How to to set default value and text with select2

Comment: Why not select the default value with PHP? Is there some user interaction before the default should be selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `change` trigger for update in select2 after set value

```
$('#cross_match_id').val(data.cross_match_id).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// to select the first blank value
("#id").select2().select2("val", null);

// to select specific value
$("#id").select2().select2("val", 'oneofthevaluehere');
```

Comment: Can you show using the code above? als the only available for me is the value of the option.